How do I hide/disable the distracting progress bar from the bottom pane corner of SQL Developer?
I have a visually distracting "progress bar" in the bottom pane of SQL developer that keeps moving from left to right and back, even if no query is running or when I am not doing anything.

How do I turn this thing off?
I experience this behavior on Windows with an installation from a zip file. The version is 24.3.284.2209.
I have not installed any additional tools - the only modification after unpacking the zip file was to add a connection in the connection manager.

I wouldn't know (but Jeff might). Meanwhile, move the SQL Developer window "down" so that annoying progress bar becomes hidden behind the Taskbar :)

If you want to hide the whole area you can turn off the status bar from the View menu, but that hides other potentially-useful information, obviously. Which version are you seeing this in? I only see the progress bar at start-up, when it's running an (oddly long-running) IndexPreferencePane task. Does Windows->Processes show anything actually running in the background? The '(6 more...)` might indicate it's doing something; maybe from an extension you've added?

@AlexPoole I have the IndexPreferencePane tasks as well when I start SQL Developer, but I am already used to it from previous installations.
I am not sure if Windows -> Processes is a menu which I am unable to find.
I have added the version number in the question.

@RenéNyffenegger - sorry, I meant View->Processes, d'oh. Maybe also View->Task Progress? I'm stuck on 22.2 which doesn't show the progress bar all the time, but I'll see if I can get a newer version - could be a recent bug maybe...

Yes, this does seem to be a bug in 24.3. (Also see Doc ID 3060354.1 which has the unpublished bug number.) Which wasn't what you asked, of course, but I don't think there is a way to hide just the progress bar, just the whole status line.

Ok, that's nice, a confirmed bug is less harmful...  if you turn your comment into an answer, I will accept it.

There doesn't seem to be a way to only hide the progress bar(s); the only way to not see them appears to be to turn off the whole status bar, which you can do from the View menu by toggling the 'Show Status Bar' item. That also hides the line/column number, insert/overwrite and modified indicators of course.
You shouldn't be seeing the progress bar constantly though. This is a bug reported via the SQL Developer forum:

SQL Developer 24.3.0.284 Infinitely scanning task process bar

and raised internally by @thatjeffsmith according to his answer there:

Our internal QA folks can reproduce this now, so we've officially logged a bug.

Which means there is also an Oracle Support document about it, 3060354.1:

Using SQL Developer version 24.3.0.284.2209, after a query is submitted in the Worksheet, the query finishes successfully. However, on the bottom of the screen in the Messages Log, it shows "Waiting for Displaying Results to finish", and never stops displaying this message with a progress indicator bar that keeps flashing.

Until that is fixed in a future release, the only workaround seems to be to hide the status bar, unfortunately.
